# How do I evaluate multiple booleans in dust.js?

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I'm using dust.js for templating in JS, and I'm having some problems with booleans. I know the following code is not supported (ref https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#wiki-if_condcondition__if_helper_Available_in_Dust_10_release) and I'm wondering which approach is the best for statements of this kind:

```
{@if cond="{has_items} && {is_member}"}
    <p>Has items, is member</p>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{?has_items}
  {?is_member}
    <p>Has items, is member</p>
  {/is_member}
{/has_items}
```

You can also create a [helper](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers), if a solution like this won't scale for you.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's possible to nest the statements, but that is more of a work-around. I was hoping there was a more elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: You could also write a new helper that better meets your needs.

Comment: Yeah, ended building helpers. That also reduced the complexity of the views :)